# is it possible to find a $\omega$ such as $\omega _n f(x) = f(\lambda x) $ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

is a test we had last week, we were asked to find an approximate value for an integral, the question was like

$$ \ I = \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx $$

prove that an approximate for $I$ can be found using this formula, where $f$ is a polynomial

$$ \hat I = \omega_0f\left(-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right) + \omega_1f(0) + \omega_2f\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right) $$

now my method was to approximate the integral using [composed trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) for three number which should give me

$$ I \approx \frac{1}{2}[f(-1) + 2f(0) + f(1)] $$

now the problem I faced was proving this relation

$$ \omega_n f(x) = f(\lambda x) $$

for $\lambda$ being $\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$

it made sense, but I couldn't for the love of god find a way to solve it or find the value of $w_n$ regardless of the polynomial degree or the coefficients of it

something like

$$ f(\lambda x) = a_{n} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}^{n} x^{n} + a_{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}^{n-1} x^{n-1} + .... + a_0 $$

spoiler alert: the correct method to find the approximate is using [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) but I want to know if the relation I was trying to prove is possible and how to?

Comment: The RHS of your formula $$ I \approx f(-1) + 2f(0) + f(1) $$ should be divided by 2.

Comment: correct! will fix it

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is not possible. There are several **quadrature** formulas. The one you are looking for is associated with Gauss as you stated. It is not equivalent to the composed trapezoidal rule. The clue is the points at which the function is evaluated are different. If you use $f(\lambda x)$ then that changes the interval of integration unless $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-1$.